# vertex sequences from igraph

Tags: list, graph, igraph

I have extracted all shortest paths using igraph and have saved it in a list file (named best). First all nodes were numbers and I added gene symbols to them. the results is:

```
library(igraph)
adjacency <- structure(list(source = structure(c(3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L), 
  .Label = c("ANXA7", "CAV1", "FLNA", "GRB7", "PRKCA"), class = "factor"), 
  Target = structure(c(5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L), 
  .Label = c("A1BG", "ANXA7", "CAV1", "GRB7", "PRKCA"), class = "factor")), 
  .Names = c("source", "Target"), 
  class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -6L)) 

graph <- graph.data.frame(adjacency, directed = FALSE)

graph
# IGRAPH UN-- 6 6 -- 
# + attr: name (v/c)
plot(graph)
```

Then acheiving shortest paths:

```
rest <- best <- list()
rest[[1]] <- get.all.shortest.paths(graph, 1, 3, mode = c("all"))$res
names <- V(graph)
best <- lapply(rest[[1]], function(rest) { names[rest]})
```

Then

```
[[1]]
Vertex sequence:
[1] "FLNA"  "PRKCA" "ANXA7"
```

also you may need dput and unlist output:

```
dput(best)
list(list(structure(c(1, 2, 3), class = "igraph.es", env = <environment>)))

unlist(best[[1]])
[1] 1 2 3
```

But what I need is just extract/count node names. Also the order is important.

```
names(best[[1]])
NULL     # I need to just list the names
length(best)
[1] 1   # number of shortest paths
> length(best[[1]])
[1] 1 # I need to count nodes in each shortest path
```

Thanks

Comment: This code generates an error: `Error in \`[.igraph.vs\`(names, rest) : invalid indexing of vertex seq`

Comment: I have checked and revised it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace this code **(names<-V(graph))** with :

```
names<-V(graph)$name
```

This will work.